# How do I receive post data in Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am having trouble figuring out why sending info to a post request to my app always shows empty (some of this omitted for brevity).

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/sendmail', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

[image]

Posting to that URL logs this in the console:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
{}
```

What gives?

Comment: Raw POST data should look like `foo=bar`. Or if you had an object like `{foo: {foo: bar} }` then this would look like `foo[foo]=bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the solution you are looking for (I am sorry, don't vote me down just for this one :) ) but I still wanted to share my own experience with postman, node and automated testing frameworks, hope it will at least allow you to carry on with what you are doing.

To my experience there is either something wrong with postman or I am missing a vital bit of information. Let me explain, when I just started using postman, I was able to successfully POST data to my node app, but then suddenly it refused to work as expected ( edit: same problem you are having here... 'body' is arriving with no data inside )... and yes I know the bit about header types and triple checked the settings in postman and what's not.

Having failed to work out what was wrong with this application and not willing to waste any more time I rolled back to using a good-old way of testing using a simple framework with a little help from HTTP library.

A very simple to use combo of [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) will let you have a bunch of control over what and how you want to test your app and basically simulate completely all aspects of interaction with your app in whichever order you require and so forth...

Comment: This looks like it was my issue. I ended up just making a test form. I should have checked to see if it was Postman before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

bodyParser middleware sets req.body based on POST content and mime type - using JSON.parse if its `*/json` or urldecode if type is `*/urlencoded`. Other body types are not supported. As already commented, you need to set header or set post type in Postman

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your client from "Text" to "JSON" in the combobox located above your POST json data

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to fix my issue.

Comment: On the top right corner, there is a button "Headers", click that and add Content-Type equals application/json